# Esther 8:17 - Is the phrase פַּֽחַד־הַיְּהוּדִ֖ים synonymous with יִרְאַ֚ת יְהֹוָ֨ה?

Tags: hebrew, megillat-esther

When studying **Esther 8:17**, we read:

> And in every province and in every city, wherever the king's order and his edict reached, [there was] joy and gladness for the Jews, a banquet and a festive day, and many of the peoples of the land became Jews because the fear of the Jews was upon them. ( וּבְכָל־מְדִינָ֨ה וּמְדִינָ֜ה וּבְכָל־עִ֣יר וָעִ֗יר מְקוֹם֙ אֲשֶׁ֨ר דְּבַר־הַמֶּ֤לֶךְ וְדָתוֹ֙ מַגִּ֔יעַ שִׂמְחָ֤ה וְשָׂשׂוֹן֙ לַיְּהוּדִ֔ים מִשְׁתֶּ֖ה וְי֣וֹם ט֑וֹב וְרַבִּ֞ים מֵֽעַמֵּ֤י הָאָ֨רֶץ֙ מִֽתְיַֽהֲדִ֔ים כִּֽי־נָפַ֥ל פַּֽחַד־הַיְּהוּדִ֖ים עֲלֵיהֶֽם )

[https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.8.17?with=all&lang=bi]

- Why would Esther 8:17 teach "Converting to Judaism" was prompted by פַּֽחַד־הַיְּהוּדִ֖ים instead of יִרְאַ֚ת יְהֹוָ֨ה ?

**Is the phrase פַּֽחַד־הַיְּהוּדִ֖ים synonymous with יִרְאַ֚ת יְהֹוָ֨ה?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not at all; in fact many commentaries say *mityahadim* means simply "claimed to be Jewish."

They were afraid of the political clout of the Jews; enlightened self-interest, that's all. The phrase is used in the megillah synonymously with "fear of Mordechai, because he was politically powerful."

Answer (score 1):

there is also another explanation...

That the word aleihemmm refers to the amalekimm .The posuk is saying that as hamans camp got scared automatically people started to b interested in becoming geirimm